# Redux Toolkit - Copy data from one slice to another

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a redux store configured using redux-toolkit with two slices: `products` and `cart`.

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    products: productsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
  },
})
```

I would like to copy some data from the `products` slice into the `cart` slice when the user clicks an "Add to cart" button in the UI. This data will include the product ID and quantity which is currently set in the `products` slice. I'd like to dispatch an action that copies that data across, instead of having to pull the data out into a component and then pass it back in through the dispatched action. Is this possible with redux toolkit? Is this a use-case for a thunk?

Answer (score -2):

Duplicating data goes against the idea of redux having a 'single source for truth' and is not recommended.

If I understand you correctly, you say you want to do the duplication (modifying the state) without dispatching that data through actions. This goes against the principle of immutability and pure functions on which redux is based.

TLDR: Redux is based on the idea of modifying a single state (with no duplication) through pure functions. Your use case goes against it all.

Comment: It's not data duplication. The quantity in the `products` state represents the user-selected value visible in the UI. When the user wants to "commit" that to the cart, the value needs to be copied across.

Comment: then you need to dispatch an action, and pass as argument the quantity and product_ID. There is no other way to change the state than with dispatch, and that's a feature.

Comment: I'm not saying there is a way to change the state without dispatch. What I'm saying is that the data necessary to modify the state exists within the state, so it seems unnecessary to pull it out and pass it back in as an action payload. One solution would be to put all the data in a single slice, but I'd like to keep it separated to make it easier to maintain.

Comment: If you want to change the state, you need to dispatch. Either you dispatch the ID and quantity, or you toggle a `confirmed` boolean. You could access the outside state from inside the slice resolver but it would break separation between slices. So practically, the answer is NO, if you like it or not.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. I'm not saying I shouldn't dispatch. When the user clicks the "Add to cart" button, of course I have to dispatch an action. What I'm asking is if it's possible to dispatch an action without having to select the data into the component first. Why? Because the necessary data exists somewhere else in state. Think of it as deriving the next state from the previous state. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, this is possible, but not while maintaining isolation between slices. If you want to isolate slices, the data has to be passed around (which is not necessarily inefficient)